# Reading text file by few users simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, text-files

I have Servlet WEB API that should read text file from file system, filter it and send reply to user. It must be capable of handling few simultaneous
users working with the same file. File will be read by BufferedReader.readline() method. Does somebody know is file locked then it is read by readline() or I shouldn't worry about that?

Comment: You should have no problem opening the file several times for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on file system synchronization: it depends on the OS. But it can be tricky.

I rather would advise to rely on synchronization in your app: create an synchronized object, for that file, each time you invoke it. Then you control everything.